# Setting maxlength and other html attributes using ASP.NET MVC helper methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently when I want to set html attributes like maxlength and autocomplete, I have to use the following syntax:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("username", ViewData["username"], new { maxlength = 20, autocomplete = "off" }) %>
```

Is there any way to do this without having to explicitly set the ViewData["username"] portion?  In other words, I want to rely on the helper method's automatic loading routine rather than having to explicitly tell it which field to load up from the ViewData.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just pass "null" as second parameter:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("username", null, new { maxlength = 20, autocomplete = "off" }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes but you have to use ViewData.Model instead of ViewData.Item()

the code in your controller should look like this (sry 4 VB.NET code)

```
Function Index()
    ViewData("Title") = "Home Page"
    ViewData("Message") = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!"

    Dim user As New User

    Return View(user)
End Function
```

now you can do this in the view

```
<%=Html.TextBox("username", Nothing, New With {.maxlength = 30})%>
```

note that the user object has a public property username

hth

Answer (score 0):

I used construction as below:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("username", "", new { @maxlength = "20", @autocomplete = "off" }) %>
```

Comment: This doesn't persist the viewstate.  What if after submission, there was a validation error that I wanted to display to the user?  Doing this would clear out the "username" textbox and force the user to start over from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

For Setting max length of TextBox you can pass "" or null for Second Parameter and set html attributes(maxlength) as third parameter

```
<%=Html.TextBox("username", "", new { @maxlength = 10 }) %>
```